# react-instantsearch refine function doesn't affect currentRefinement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, algolia, react-instantsearch

I am trying to use the new hook syntax from `react-instantsearch` with our custom pagination component, however, the `refine` function never changes the value of `currentRefinement`, which also always shows as 0. So you always see the same results, no matter how many times you hit next page.

I had wondered if it was because I was passing props to the component where it is rendered (as the props are passed as a whole to the usePagination hook), but removing them doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
<AlgoliaPagination
  hitsPerPage={hitsPerPage}
  totalHitCount={totalHitCount}
/>
```

Any help much appreciated!

```
const AlgoliaPagination: FC<IAlgoliaPaginationProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    currentRefinement,
    nbPages,
    isFirstPage,
    isLastPage,
    refine,
    createURL,
  } = usePagination(props);

  const { hitsPerPage, totalHitCount } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    refine(2)             // doesn't change currentRefinement

    refine(currentRefinement);     // doesn't change it either
  }, [currentRefinement]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.paginationRow}>
      {nbPages > 1 && (
        <div style={{ width: '20rem', height: '10px', display: 'flex' }}>
          <div
            style={{
              width: (currentRefinement / nbPages) * 100 + '%',
              backgroundColor: '#0E872E',
              height: '100%',
            }}
          ></div>
          <div
            style={{
              width: (1 - currentRefinement / nbPages) * 100 + '%',
              backgroundColor: '#0E872E',
              opacity: '0.3',
              height: '100%',
            }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      )}
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '1rem' }}>
        {!isFirstPage && (
          <div
            onClick={(event) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              refine(currentRefinement - 1);
              window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
            }}
          >
            <LinkButton
              link={createURL(currentRefinement - 1)}
              title={`Load previous ${hitsPerPage} results`}
              colorClasses={'stemGreenBg styled-thin-btn text-white'}
              disableScroll={true}
              target="_self"
            />
          </div>
        )}
        {!isLastPage && (
          <div
            onClick={(event) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              refine(currentRefinement + 1);
              window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
            }}
          >
            <LinkButton
              link={createURL(currentRefinement + 1)}
              title={`Load next ${
                isLastPage
                  ? totalHitCount - hitsPerPage * currentRefinement
                  : hitsPerPage
              } results`}
              colorClasses={'stemGreenBg styled-thin-btn text-white'}
              disableScroll={true}
              target="_self"
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AlgoliaPagination;
```